# background sizes to cater for all iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I would like to know the background pixel dimensions for all current iOS devices (iPhone and iPad image set below). It seems to be somewhat confusing and all the posts I've found aren't current or don't give a clear cut answer.
[image]

Comment: Did the following worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following link contains all the latest devices and resolutions which will be best suitable for your query
**[Check This link](http://iosres.com/)**

**iPhone**

1x - 640 x 1136

2x - 750 x 1334

3x - 1242 x 2208

**iPad**

1x - 1536 x 2048

2x - 2048 x 2732